# A weighted graph with adjacency list representation using ArrayList

Tags: java, graph, adjacency-list

I am confused when someone uses ArrayList to implement a weighted graph with adjacency list representation.  For example, in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-in-java-using-priorityqueue/, the codes are

```
List<List<Node> > adj = new ArrayList<List<Node> >(); 

// Initialize list for every node 
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) { 
    List<Node> item = new ArrayList<Node>(); 
    adj.add(item); 
} 

// Inputs for the DPQ graph 
adj.get(0).add(new Node(1, 9)); 
adj.get(0).add(new Node(2, 6)); 
adj.get(0).add(new Node(3, 5)); 
adj.get(0).add(new Node(4, 3)); 

adj.get(2).add(new Node(1, 2)); 
adj.get(2).add(new Node(3, 4));
```

[image]

I would think

```
adj.get(0).add(new Node(1, 9));
```

should be

```
adj.get(0).add(new Node(1, 4));
```

since the weight between edge 0 and 1 is 4, not 9.

What have I missed?

Comment: I think that the code is creating a different example than the one in the image.

Comment: Thanks Loris!  You are correct.  The image has a different output printed in the article which I overlooked.  I did not think out of box.